# Using stringstream inside a loop to extract a number from few strings

Tags: c++, for-loop, stringstream

I'm currently practicing with stringstreams to extract values from a string. In this simple code, user enters a name and a number (separated by a space), this string is stored in "input". Then, it's passed to "stream" and it separates the name and the number, which are stored in "name" and "number". Then, the number is output with std::cout. This process is done a few times with different names and numbers.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::stringstream stream;
    std::string name;
    double amount;

    for (;;) {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);      // enter a name, a whitespace and a number
        stream.str(input);
        stream >> name >> amount;           // problem here
        std::cout << amount << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Problem: Only the number of the first entered input is stored in "amount". The numbers of the next inputs will not be stored in "amount" (amount always has the same number inside). Maybe, there is something I don't know about stringstreams...

Comment: It will be easier to see what's going on if the code shows **both** of the input values, i.e., both `amount` and `name`.

Comment: I have checked name and it doesn't print ok. Only the first name entered is printed, just like the number, only the first entered number is printed. No matter how many times you loop.

Comment: @AnselmoGPP You need to reset the `std::stringstream` after you used once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem: Only the number of the first entered input is stored in
>   "amount". The numbers of the next inputs will not be stored in
>   "amount" (amount always has the same number inside). Maybe, there is
>   something I don't know about stringstreams...

Yes. You have forgot to **reset** the `std::stringstream` after you used once.

In order to do that, you need to set both the *underlying sequence*(contents of a stringstream) to an empty string using [`std::stringstream::str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) and also the *fail*(if any) and *eof flags* with [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear).

That means, end of your `for` loop you need this: **[SEE LIVE](https://www.ideone.com/3BpkHX)**

```
int main()
{
   ....
   ....
   for (;;)
   {
      ...
      ...
      stream.str( std::string() );   // or stream.str(""); 
      stream.clear();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I checked it and **stream.clear()** solved the problem (thank you!). However, **stream.str(std::string())** or **stream.str("")** were not neccesary for the program to work fine.

Comment: Ok. So, to really reset a stringstream, you have to **stream.str(std::string())** and **stream.clear()**. I'll bear it in mind. In this little program it's not strictly neccesary to erase the contents of stringstream because they are overwritten later, but it's good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an **Input StringStream** `std::istringstream` instead, which is dedicated to working as an input stream (like `std::cin`), unlike `std::stringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::istringstream stream; // Note the extra i
    std::string name;
    double amount;

    for (;;) {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        stream.str(input);
        stream >> name >> amount;
        std::cout << amount << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Input: Hello 3.14
>
> Output: 3.14
>
> Input: World 2.71
>
> Output: 2.71

Comment: @HansGP Are u sure you added the extra `i` in `istringstream`?

Comment: Yes, Gill Bates, I have tried that multiple times. I even copied your code and compiled it. It still doesn't work as expected. This is strange... Maybe it is a compiler problem? I am using Visual Studio Community 2017

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that reading position is undefined when `str(string)` is called.
As a result `stream` goes to an error state, [here is a proof](https://wandbox.org/permlink/973AvjbdgFKdb03n).

The best way to fix it is to move scope of `stream` inside a loop:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::string name;
    double amount;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) {
        std::stringstream stream(input);
        stream >> name >> amount;
        std::cout << amount << " " << name << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is [proof that it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/44qcW2LuBHDDTWg2). In fact it is best to move [more variables inside a loop](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rNGKo8CwxEZuaLwt).

Comment: Yeah, moving the stringstream variable declaraction inside the loop solves the problem. Thank you. @JeJo also offered a solution that I think is even more efficient (to use **stream.clear()**).